# Shell Script to generate next hundred ip addresses

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

If I have an IP address say 192.168.1.2, I need to generate the next 100 IPs such that it keeps adding to the base ip.

I tried to execute `echo 192.168.1.{2..102}` this works fine but I need a generic code that can generate as many IP addresses specified with the base IP address using Shell Script.

Comment: What should it do if the input base address is 192.168.1.254? What about 192.168.255.200?

Comment: Why a shell script? Why the next 100? I would suggest that you look for something to generate IP addresses within a specified subnet.

Comment: need to add a simulating devices with those ips

Comment: `BASE=2; seq $BASE $((BASE + 100))` will give you 100 numbers starting  from 2 in shell, but as tripleee noted, it is not very helpful to generate IPs which are not `/24`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while (( i <= 100 ))
do
        echo "x.y.z.$i"
        i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for to iterate through a list created by the command `seq`. Then, just modify the numbers in `seq` as first and last number

```
#!/bin/bash

START=0
END=100

for I in $(seq $START $END)
do
    echo "192.168.0.$I"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If I need to change up to second octet then I should be able to change.
For example. `198.168.X.Y`. I need to generate the ip for X and Y

If I need to change up to three octets then I should be able to change.

Am looking for a solution for this. `seq -f 198.168.1.%g 1 100` works fine, need a script that can change the other octets

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses are, of course, simply unsigned 32 bit numbers.  However they are usually expressed as bytes, in decimal, with dots between the numbers.

So, if you need to use this "*dotted quad*" representation you can just convert the starting one back to an integer, count out how many you want, and for each one you count up, print it back as a dotted quad.

With any shell supporting arithmetic expressions (with bitwise operators, and for added convenience, arrays), it's easy:

```
#!/bin/ksh

ip="192.168.240.240"

num=100

set -A iparr $(echo $ip | sed 's/\./ /g')

nip=$((iparr[0] << 24))
nip=$((nip | iparr[1] << 16))
nip=$((nip | iparr[2] << 8))
nip=$((nip | iparr[3]))

lnip=$((nip + num))

while [ $nip -lt $lnip ]; do
    let $((nip++))
    iparr[0]=$((nip >> 24))
    iparr[1]=$(((nip >> 16) & 255))
    iparr[2]=$(((nip >> 8) & 255))
    iparr[3]=$((nip & 255))
    printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" ${iparr[0]} ${iparr[1]} ${iparr[2]} ${iparr[3]}
done
```

(It's not so easy with an older shell though -- and neither `awk` nor `expr` do bitwise operations on integers very easily.  But then maybe the tool you're feeding these numbers to will accept plain integers, or hex numbers, so you may not really need to use dotted quad notation.)